# How to bind emmet "wrap with abbreviation" in Sublime 3?

Tags: sublimetext3

Previously, it worked with the command ctrl + shift + g, but for some reason it does not work now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this in User Keybinding:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+g"], "command": "emmet_wrap_with_abbreviation" },
```